# Site Template - Enforce unique value for title column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have made a Title column of a list to `enforce unique values` in it. Then I took the template of this site and created a new sub-site.

In new site when I go to the same list, the title column is again the normal column and it is not taking unique values

why does it get changed in new site?

Comment: Hello Vikash! Are you creating this site in the same site collection in which the template is created or in a different site collection?

Comment: and also the base Site Template for the site that you want to make template out of!

Comment: it is in the same site collection..

Answer (score 1):

Vikash, I understand it would be much easier if SharePoint would keep the Enforce unique values setting in the new list created by template.
What you can do instead is create a Visual Studio sandboxed solution for adding a list template to a site collection and you'll have greater flexibility in setting column's properties.

Comment: I just need that when a site is created from any template then the list should be same as the list in template..(Only Enforce unique value property is coming different)